# can we run arrow function without useEffect()?

Tags: firebase, react-native, use-effect, arrow-functions

I have a function **loadListings()** in react native app it gets data from real time firebase database and renders it on on page in  `<Flatlist />`

function..

```
    let data = [];
    listingRef.orderByChild("created_at").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      data = [];
      snapshot.forEach((listing) => {
        data.push(listing.val());
      });
      setListings(data);
      setLoading(false);

    });
  };
```

and finally

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadListings();
  }, []);
```

Can I use it without the effect hook?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: I wanna put a check if is internet available or not. If not available then load listings from caches

Comment: when page loads initially network status is always null and after milliseconds it changes to true. and effect hook will not be let the function to be reaload

Comment: when I try outside the effect hook it gives an error saying too many re-renders

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Based on [official documentation for useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)  the `[]` empty array at the end means what `loadListings` function will be executed ones when this component will be mounted.

Comment: useNetInfo() hook return four objects every time when network status changes. So how can I use this to load listings every time when network status changes

Comment: It will be perfect if you share your source code, sorry, it is still unclear for me because of what you describe in a question and what you wrote in comment. use effect(()=> {...},[Value here])

Comment: Ok let give it a try.